# Insert categories into Magento Database directly

Tags: magento

I have a bidding(phpprobid) site with categories and product. I've extracted the categories from the database table and put it in a csv file. I was wondering if I can insert those values (categories) into Magento's Database so that I don't have to create each categories one by one.

Is it possible to do so? If yes in which table do I have to insert and what other attributes I need to maintain ?

Thank you

Comment: check out a few extensions that allow quick imports. uRapidFlow is awesome for this.

Answer (score 2):

chipShot's comment is the right direction. While you can insert them directly at the DB level, that tends to avoid important tables in Magento's EAV layout. You're better off writing an import using the framework or downloading someone else's module to the same effect.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe